# Tomcat: SEVERE: Error loading WebappClassLoader

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

PLEASE DO NOT MARK AS DUPLICATE, FOR OTHER SOLUTIONS DID NOT HELP YET!

I'm getting 404 in my browser trying to run this tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

I actually do not even see a WebContent/WEB-INF/classes folder.
Why isn't it generated?

I only saw solutions here on SO telling to clean the project, restart Eclipse, and so on... But non helped in my situation. I'm using Tomcat 6, dynamic web module version 2.5.

```
May 13, 2013 8:17:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
May 13, 2013 8:17:01 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:de.vogella.jersey.first' did not find a matching property.
May 13, 2013 8:17:02 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
May 13, 2013 8:17:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 524 ms
May 13, 2013 8:17:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 13, 2013 8:17:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
May 13, 2013 8:17:02 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  de.vogella.jersey.first
May 13, 2013 8:17:02 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class de.vogella.jersey.first.Hello
May 13, 2013 8:17:02 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
May 13, 2013 8:17:02 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17 01/17/2013 03:31 PM'
May 13, 2013 8:17:03 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
May 13, 2013 8:17:03 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
May 13, 2013 8:17:03 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/15  config=null
May 13, 2013 8:17:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1145 ms
```

And there is still no classes folder!!!

Comment: You should create a `WEB-INF` and `WEB-INF/lib` folder, then put the `jersey-server` (and possibly `jersey-core`) jar in there.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. try to put required JAR in lib folder

Comment: All of them are there! client/common/container-servlet/container-servlet-core/server

Comment: If cleaning and recompiling your project isn't working, try making a new one.

Comment: I tried it at least with 5 different projects!

Comment: Did you create a "Dynamic web project" using Eclipse? When I redo that tutorial I can see WebContent/WEB-INF/lib...

Comment: @StefanLindenberg I did! I can already see WebContent/WEB-INF/lib but not the /WEB-INF/classes

Comment: @StefanLindenberg what version of ApacheWink/Jersey are you using?

Comment: Is the auto build function enabled? eclipse top menu -> Project -> Build automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Vogel's example is using Jersey 1.5. If you are using Jersey 2.0 & Servlet 2.X, some properties in the web.xml file need to be changed. The web-app properties should reflect the Servlet version you are using. Also, the ServletContainer is now in the org.glassfish.jersey.servlet package. So the servlet-class property should be specified as follows:

```
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

For example, for Servlet 2.5, the web.xml file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns   /javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <display-name>de.vogella.jersey.first</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>de.vogella.jersey.first</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This information can be found in the [Jersey 2.0 User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html), Chapter 4, Deploying a RESTful Web Service.

Also, I found that I needed to set the url-pattern to:

```
    <url-pattern>/rest/hello</url-pattern>
```

to get it to work, so I still need to investigate this issue.

Comment: I'm afraid I will not be able to test this anymore, since I am no longer working on the project. Still an upvote for your efforts! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem; however, I've was stuck for a day. It is because of the versions of the jars most likely.  I had set a jar which was probably picked up 1st. in the class path and it was the wrong version of course, or compiled with a different version of Java maybe.  I've seen this before. So I started over from scratch paying attention to the jars and versions numbers installing only what was needed and it worked like a champ. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps (hope you are using Eclipse) and see if it helps getting closer to the issue.

1. Navigate:: "Right Click (project Name) --> Properties --> Source" Tab and make sure "project/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes" is selected as default output folder.
2. Navigate "Window(Menu) --> Show View --> Other --> General --> Navigator" and then go to "project/WebContent/WEB-INF/" and check if "classes" folder is there are not.
3. If not, then navigate "Window(Menu) --> Show View --> Other --> General --> Markers" and see if its showing any build path errors. If so, correct the errors and you should be good.

Comment: In 1. you mean properties-source-JAVA_BUILD_PATH-source? If yes, then I get "Default output folder: de.vogella.jersey.first/build/classes". As for 2. There is no classes folder under WEB-INF as already mentioned. As for 3. I get no errors but the warning: Description Resource Path Location Type
Classpath entry org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/ApacheWink will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.   de.vogella.jersey.first  P/de.vogella.jersey.first Classpath Dependency Validator Message

Comment: @user1423640: This means that your compiled classes are getting generated in "de.vogella.jersey.first/build/classes" folder. Can you check , if there are ".class" in the folder/subfolder? Also, first is causing second. You may want to change the output location to WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: Also go to user library configuration and un-check the system class path setting for your user library.

Comment: BTW I can see"classes" under "build" ONLY in the navigator but not in the project explorer, and it IS empty. I moved it to web-inf anyway, but nothing changed.

Comment: Where can I uncheck the system class path setting?

Comment: @user1423640 :1. I meant you to change the the configuration for build out to generate the .class files in WEB-INF/classes folder by visiting and modifying "Right Click (project Name) --> Properties --> Source". 2. To change the system class path, follow "Windows -> preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries -> Select Your Library -> Edit -> Uncheck System library".